# how can I display the contents of an email to a website?

Tags: php, email, imap

I would like to display the body contents of an email. I have tried IMAP in php but something is VERY wrong. The IMAP isn't picking up the body of my message. It is picking up ONLY the signature in the body. So I am looking for alternative methods of reading email body contents to a webpage.

here is the original document of my email:

http://pastebin.com/WQra335P

the disclaimer/copyright blur is being grabbed by IMAP but nothing else in the body is being displayed. anyone have alternative methods of reading email from gmail or any other site that can display the contents to a webpage?

I have given up on making IMAP read it because no one has been able to figure out the problem...I have spent hours so I give up but here is the code...

```
<?php
    /* connect to gmail */
    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
    $username = 'username@gmail.com';
    $password = 'password';

    /* try to connect */
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

    /* grab emails */
    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

    /* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
    if($emails) {

        /* begin output var */
        $output = '';

        /* put the newest emails on top */
        rsort($emails);

        /* for every email... */
        foreach($emails as $email_number) {

            /* get information specific to this email */
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $email_number, 0);
            $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 2);
            echo $message;
            echo imap_qprint($message);
            $message = imap_qprint($message);
            echo imap_8bit ($message);
            $DateFormatted = str_replace("-0500", "", $overview[0] -> date);

            /* output the email header information */
            $output .=  $overview[0] -> subject ;
            $output .=  $DateFormatted ;

            //$bodyFormatted = preg_replace("/This e-mail(.*)/","",$message);
            //$bodyFormatted = preg_replace("/Ce courriel(.*)/","",$bodyFormatted);
            /* output the email body */
            $output .=  $message;

        }

    echo $output;

    }

    /* close the connection */
    imap_close($inbox);

?>
```

Comment: Can you post the `IMAP` code you have tried to get the message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Addition to what DmitryK suggested,

Adding the below makes everything work fine without the random "=" signs. The Str_replace is used to remove the "="s generated over the pages.

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, "1.1"); 
$message = str_replace("=", "", $message);
```

I dont know 100% why the "="s are generated randomly but this is most likely due to some encryption issue from the Exchange Server's side as our server is about 10 years old.

Comment: Make sure you use utf-8. If that is the case, I would recommend you to use quoted_printable_decode() instead. It removes the "=".

Otherwise you also have to encode it to utf-8.
utf-8_encode(quoted_printable_decode());

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with the multi-part messages (looking at your pastebin e-mail sample).
As a test try using this line:

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, "1.1");
```

Plain text version lives under 1.1
HTML version is 1.2
The signature is in the next part - it is 2. And this is what you retrieve in your code sample.

Comment: Thank you, I was using "$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, "1.1"); " and thats why I was getting the random headers in addition to my body text, adding the .1 fixed the headers but the "="s still persist.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the raw email content (the stuff with all the headers etc)

If so, try using [plancacke email parser](https://github.com/plancake/official-library-php-email-parser)

I have used it before with good success.

```
$emailParser = new PlancakeEmailParser(...raw email content...);

$emailTo = $emailParser->getTo();
$emailSubject = $emailParser->getSubject();
$emailCc = $emailParser->getCc();
$emailDeliveredToHeader = $emailParser->getHeader('Delivered-To');
$emailBody = $emailParser->getPlainBody();
$emailHtml = $emailParser->getHTMLBody();
```

Answer (score -1):

Gmail has some different IMAP settings, follow the original code more closely:

http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap

Comment: I have the exact same code, it doesnt work for MY email header or emails that come from the exchange server to the gmail account. IMAP cant read anything but the signature. However, if I take the same email contents and email them to gmail account from gmail or email then it does read them....something to do with the format or headers of my email that comes from exchange server to gmail. What those header are I posted on pastebin link in my post above

Comment: Exchange server is a different beast, it doesn't comply with IMAP standards completely.

Comment: What can I do in that case? to summarize it gmail-gmail for me works but exchange server-gmail doesnt work.. gmail-gmail meaning a gmail email sent to a gmail account.. or yahoo-gmail meaning yahoo email sent to gmail account